# Laravel API ResourceCollection WhenLoaded

Tags: laravel

I try to include a relationship in my resource array if it has been eager loaded, but don't get it working.

Anyone has an idea, how I can check the relationships in the ResourceCollection?

Database schema looks like this:
[image]

Here is my Post Model

```
class Post extends Model
{
    function categories() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
    }
}
```

Here is my Category Model

```
class Category extends Model
{
    function posts() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
    }
}
```

Here is my Post Controller

```
Class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return new PostResourceCollection(Post::with("categories")->get());
    }
}
```

Here is my Post ResourceCollection

```
class PostResourceCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {

        return [
            'data' => $this->collection->transform(function($page){
                return [
                    'type' => 'posts',
                    'id' => $page->id,
                    'attributes'    => [
                        'name' => $page->title,
                    ],
                ];
            }),
            //'includes' => ($this->whenLoaded('categories')) ? 'true' : 'false',
            //'includes' => ($this->relationLoaded('categories')) ? 'true' : 'false',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you manage this to work?

Comment: don't deal with Laravel anymore but found below answer. That seemed to work at this point in time

Comment: Then you may like to answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57478314/adding-filter-to-eloquent-resource-to-attach-relationship-conditionally/57486061?noredirect=1#comment101459987_57486061

Answer (score 2):

Maybe too late, below solution is a workaround for this case:

```
return [
    ...,
    'includes' => $this->whenLoaded('categories', true),
];
```

Loading custom attribute:

```
return [
    ...,
    'includes' => $this->whenLoaded('categories', fn() => $this->categories->name),
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You relationship is wrong, **a post belongs to many categories** while **a category has many posts** so change:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    function posts() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post', 'category_post');
    }
}
```

to

```
class Category extends Model
{
    function posts() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'category_post');
    }
}
```

Now when you load the post you can load the categories also:

```
$posts = Post::with('categories')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Tested it and it does not have any effect. Just to be sure, loading of categories is not the issue. I just cannot reference it in my ResourceCollection. Like described here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources#conditional-relationships

Comment: Normally a post belongs only to one category since the concept of categories is, that they are hierarchically. Otherwise they are tags. 

But lets go for the example: The relationships are correct in the question as you can read also in documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many. Both ends are `belongsToMany`

Answer (score 0):

got it.. That was the missing piece. if anyone has a better solution for this it would be much appreciated.

```
foreach ($this->collection as $item) {
  if ($item->relationLoaded('categories')) {
    $included = true;
}
```