# Adding filter to eloquent resource to attach relationship conditionally

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship, laravel-eloquent-resource

Laravel 5.8
PHP 7.4

I want to load the relationships conditionally like

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts
```

and

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/1 are my end points now, I want to load comments like
```

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/?include=comments` and

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/1/?include=comments
```

If the query parameter is there, only then it should load comments with posts or it should load only posts/post

I am doing this by referring a [blog post](https://medium.com/@matthew.erskine/laravel-5-5-eloquent-resources-get-query-param-filters-9101edad2d95)

now, **RequestQueryFilter**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Resources;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class RequestQueryFilter
{
    public function attach($resource, Request $request = null)
    {
        $request = $request ?? request();
        return tap($resource, function($resource) use($request) {
            $this->getRequestIncludes($request)->each(function($include) use($resource) {
                $resource->load($include);
            });
        });
    }
    protected function getRequestIncludes(Request $request)
    {
        // return collect(data_get($request->input(), 'include', [])); //single relationship
        return collect(array_map('trim', explode(',', data_get($request->input(), 'include', [])))); //multiple relationships
    }
}
```

and in helper

```
<?php
if ( ! function_exists('filter') ) {
    function filter($attach) 
    {
        return app('filter')->attach($attach);
    }
}
?>
```

in PostController

```
public funciton show(Request $request, Post $post) {
    return new PostResource(filter($post));
}
```

but when I am trying to retrieve

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/1/?include=comments getting no comments, with no error in log
```

A work around will be PostResource

```
 public function toArray($request)
    {
        // return parent::toArray($request);
        $data = [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->title,
            'body' => $this->content,
        ];

        $filter = $request->query->get('include', '');

        if($filter){
          $data[$filter] = $this->resource->$filter;
        }

        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at this package  - it should fit perfectly for your needs: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-query-builder

Comment: @jtwes thank you for your response, already looked that, it seems to be for query builder and I am using eloquent resource, so I would like to make it work with out that package, any way thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to load the relationships conditionally like

### Lazy Eager Loading using the `load()` call

The Lazy Eager Loading accomplishes the same end results as `with()` in Laravel, however, not automatically. **For example**:

`?include=comments`

```php
// Get all posts.
$posts = Post::without('comments')->all();

if (request('include') == 'comments')) {
    $posts->load('comments');
}

return PostResource::collection($posts);
```

Alternativelly, you could require the `include` query string to be an array:

`?include[]=comments&include[]=tags`

```php
// Validate the names against a set of allowed names beforehand, so there's no error.
$posts = Post::without(request('includes'))->all();

foreach (request('includes') as $include) {
    $posts->load($include);
}

return PostResource::collection($posts);
```

The call *`without()` is only required in case you defined your model to automatically eager load the relationships you want to conditionally load.*

### With all data filtered in Controller, just make sure to display only loaded relations in your `PostResource`

```php
public function toArray($request) {
    $data = [...];

    foreach ($this->relations as $name => $relation)
    {
        $data[$name] = $relation;
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: This will behave similar to my work around and need to implement in every resource, I want to create something generic.

Comment: How about creating a parent class to extend in PostResource, like `PostResource extends InjectRelationResource` ? The logic would inject any loaded relationship to the data output, this what i can think now

Comment: Maybe that will work fine, but we also need to consider specifying attributes and also it should allow pagination. Not having a clear idea, but seems that may be a good solution.

Comment: It still ain't that clear to me what you are trying to achieve, apart from relations, do you want include the resource fields conditionally too?

Comment: Just what normal resource and resource collection offers, specifying what you want to return, relationships and pagination, but we can focus on relationships for now.

Comment: not conditionally, but want to exclude `created_at`, `updated_at` and certain fields from resource.

Comment: I c, by setting up resources you actually achieve that individually, however, how about setting up the `$hidden` property in the model?

Comment: For resource, I may not need but inside app, at some point I may need that properties, so not out putting for that. anyway formatting data is ResourceCollection's job, so I would like to achieve in this level.

Comment: Please, clarify to me what's the issue then... :)

Comment: Have you looked in to the answer I have provided? you can see, it is working for resource and not for collection, this is current status, the question is simple, I want the resource to include relationships optionally based on query parameters, with out breaking any of it's default properties/abilities, neither making it overworking .

Answer (score 1):

I would create a custom resource for the posts with

```
php artisan make_resource
```

command.
E.g. PostResource.
The toArray function of the resource must return the data.

**PostResource.php**

```
public function toArray($request){
     $data =['title' => $this->resource->title,

    'body' => $this->resource->body,

    'images' => new ImageCollection($this->whenLoaded('images')),
            ];

     $filter = $request->query->get('filter', '');

     if($filter){
      $data['comments'] => new CommentCollection($this->resource->comments);

     }
  return $data;
}
```

Also, for collections, you need to create a ResourceCollection.

**PostResourceCollection.php**

```
class PostResourceCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'data' => $this->collection,
        ];
    }
}
```

In your controller:
**PostsController.php**

```
   //show one post
     public function show(Post $post, Request $request)
        {

           /**this response is for API or vue.js if you need to generate view, pass the resource to the view */
            return $this->response->json( new PostResource($post));
        } 
    //list of posts
        public function index(Request $request)
            {
               $posts = Post::all();
               /**this response is for API or vue.js if you need to generate view, pass the resource to the view */
                return $this->response->json( new PostResourceCollection($posts));
            }
```

Comment: I have resource, let me try your code, but `comments` can be something else like images and can be `comments` and `images`, so I can not make it static.

Comment: Your code needs a little bit correction ` $filter = $request->query->get('include', '');

        if($filter){
          $data['comments'] = $this->resource->comments;
        }` and it will work, but need to make it dynamic and would like to make a generic solution, it will only work for a particular resource.

Comment: dynamic will be ` $filter = $request->query->get('include', '');

        if($filter){
          $data[$filter] = $this->resource->$filter;
        }` only for post, do not want to add this filter in every resouse, as job of resource is formatting the data not filtering.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu, yes, sorry, i was confused by the title of the issue, that is why I used fiter:   try this:$includes = collect(explode(',', $request->query->get('includes', '')));

Comment: Just tried, not seems to be working, getting only post resource.

Comment: I have added a partial solution, can you please look into it, may be you can suggest something.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu , I have updated my response I hope it helps

Comment: no it does not seems to be working, I tried, but it did not work, it is not including relationships in collection.

Comment: have you tried with $this->resource->whenLoaded() ?

Comment: Check my answer, it is working for resource with whenLoaded, but not working for collection.

Answer (score 0):

**Partial Solution**

It will need a small change in resource class

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    // return parent::toArray($request);
    $data = [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'title' => $this->title,
        'body' => $this->body,
        'comments' => new CommentCollection($this->whenLoaded('comments')),
        'images' => new ImageCollection($this->whenLoaded('images')),
    ];
    return $data;
}
```

and it will load comments and images if loaded and that depends on the `include` query parameter, if that is not included, it will not load the relationship.

However,

In post collection

```
return [
    'data' => $this->collection->transform(function($post){
        return [
            'id' => $post->id,
            'title' => $post->title,
            'body' => $post->body,
            'comments' => new CommentCollection($post->whenLoaded('comments')),
            'images' => new ImageCollection($post->whenLoaded('images')),
        ];
    }),
];
```

will results in

> "Call to undefined method App\Models\Customer::whenLoaded()",, if anyone suggests a complete solution, it will be a great help, if I will able to do, it I will update here.